# Logging best approaches

Tags: c#, logging

I'm preparing to start developing a new application which has to connect to different API's of different machines which will make the application fairly complicated.

What approaches are there to implement logging into my application, and what are their respective advantages and disadvantages? To be more precise, I'm looking into the best way to export the logs to an external logfile.

---

Details:

Currently I'm using a system where I add a logentry to a list of logs which I then process line by line through a backgroundworker.

My idea behind this is that by putting the logsprocessing on a different thread I will not disturb the main UI-thread or any other threads for that matter.

However, I think that I'm still using unnecessary resources in my UI-thread because I'm compiling and adding my logentry on the UI-thread. Should I put the actual entry as well on a different thread?

Here is the code that I currently use:

```
        List<LoggingClass> Logs;
        BackgroundWorker bgLogs;

        public void startLogging()
        {
            // INITIALIZE THE BACKGROUND WORKER
            bgLogs = new BackgroundWorker();

            // SET UP THE BACKGROUND WORKER
            bgLogs.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bgLogs.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
            bgLogs.DoWork += bgLogs_DoWork;

            // START THE BACKGROUND WORKER
            bgLogs.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void bgLogs_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            while (worker.IsBusy == true)
            {
                if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Logs != null && Logs.Count > 0)
                    {
                        processLogs();
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
        public void log(DateTime logTimeStamp, LogType logType, string logContent)
        {
            // CHECK IF THE LIST OF LOGS EXISTS
            if (Logs == null)
            {
                Logs = new List<LoggingClass>();
            }

            // CREATE A TEMPORARY LOG ENTRY
            LoggingClass tmpLog = new LoggingClass();
            tmpLog.TimeStamp = logTimeStamp;
            tmpLog.Type = logType;
            tmpLog.Content = logContent;

            // ADD THE LOG TO THE LIST OF LOGS
            Logs.Add(tmpLog);

            // CLEAR THE TEMPRARY LOG
            tmpLog = null;
        }

        private void processLogs()
        {
            string logOutput = string.Empty;

            do
            {
                // CREATE A TEMPORARY LOG ENTRY
                LoggingClass tmpLog = Logs[0];

                // APPEND THE LOG DATA INTO THE TEMPORARY STRING
                logOutput += string.Format("[{0}]\t{1}\t{2}", tmpLog.TimeStamp.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"), tmpLog.Type.ToString(), tmpLog.Content) + Environment.NewLine;

                // REMOVE THE FIRST LOG ENTRY
                Logs.RemoveAt(0);

            } while (Logs.Count > 0);

            // GET THE FILENAME FOR THE LOGGING FILE
            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            string logFile = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Application.ExecutablePath, @"..\LOGS\" + currentDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "_log.log"));

            // CHECK AND CREATE IF NEEDED THE LOGS DIRECTORY
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(logFile));

            // ADD THE LOGGINGCONTENT TO THE LOG FILE
            File.AppendAllText(logFile, logOutput, Encoding.UTF8);

        }




        class LoggingClass
        {
            public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
            public LogType Type { get; set; }
            public string Content { get; set; }
        }
```

Are there any issues with using this method?

Comment: Logging goes into the Area of Exception handling. And there are two articles on the mater that I like a lot and link quite often. Particular the 2nd one relates to "what to log": http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx | http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET Where you save the log to is a minor detail overall. No target will ever be 100% reliable.

Comment: I have always gone for queueing log outputs to one only logging thread,  That thread is the only one to manage the log file and insulates the rest of the app from any latencies resulting from disk writes.  It makes management of logs really easy - common stuff like opening a new file every day, or whenever the file reaches some size, or doing backup copies, is easy, and the rest of the app needs to know nothing about it:)

Comment: My quick answer: use nlog and review the source code to understand how it works. I understand the desire to learn through creation but do you really want to commit resources to maintaining something that isn't the core value of your application?

Comment: For all of that you can use log4net. It comes in a nuget package. Also, there are viewers you can use to filter and highlight items

Comment: @MartinJames, do you care to elaborate? How do you queue your log into the a thread. Is this similar as what I was doing first? Create a list to hold your log entries and process this list with a backgroundworker?